# Why can Mathematica not use the compiled code?

Tags: compile

```
    footandkneestates = 
     Compile[{{t1, _Real}, {tb, _Real}, {tc, _Real}, {kneephase121, \
    _Real}, {kneephase122, _Real}, {kneephase31, _Real}, {kneephase32, \
   _Real}, {footphase11, _Real}, {footphase12, _Real}, {footphase21, \
   _Real}, {footphase22, _Real}, {footphase31, _Real}, {footphase32, \
   _Real}, {tfprevious, _Real}, {tfnext, _Real}, {\[CapitalDelta]t, \
   _Real}}, Which[
       tfprevious <= t1 < tfprevious + tb \[CapitalDelta]t, {kneephase121,
         kneephase122, footphase11, footphase12}, 
           tfprevious + tb \[CapitalDelta]t <= t1 < 
        tfprevious + tc \[CapitalDelta]t, {kneephase121, kneephase122, 
       footphase21, footphase22}, 
       tfprevious + tc \[CapitalDelta]t <= t1 < tfnext, {kneephase31, 
        kneephase32, footphase31, footphase32}]]
```

I have this function, which only accepts reals and when I give this set of numbers:

```
{0.1, 0.4, 0.8, -0.564822, 0.592935, -0.264433, 0.471983, -0.336753, \
0.14798, -0.0964996, 0.768075, 0.722187, 0.691703, 0, 0.403326, \
0.403326}
```

as the function arguments it proceeds with an uncompiled evaluation, this is the input:

```
footandkneestates[0.1, 0.4, 0.8, -0.564822, 0.592935, -0.264433, 0.471983, -0.336753, \
    0.14798, -0.0964996, 0.768075, 0.722187, 0.691703, 0, 0.403326, \
    0.403326]
```

and this is the output:

```
CompiledFunction:Compiled expression {-0.564822,0.592935,-0.336753,0.14798} should be a machine-size real number.
CompiledFunction:Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 1; proceeding \
with uncompiled evaluation
{-0.564822, 0.592935, -0.336753, 0.14798}
```

Can anyone help me out why I can't used the compiled version of this function with the dataset I provided?

Answer (score 27):

This is a very subtle issue. It is important to `Compile` that it has always the same return type, no matter what happens at runtime. Note that `Which` returns `Null` as default value. Since the return value of the function is meant to be a 4-vector in some cases, we have to assign also a 4-vector (e.g., `{0., 0., 0., 0.}`) as default return value of `Which`. So this should work:

```
footandkneestates = 
 Compile[{{t1, _Real}, {tb, _Real}, {tc, _Real}, {kneephase121, _Real}, {kneephase122, _Real}, {kneephase31, _Real}, {kneephase32, _Real}, {footphase11, _Real}, {footphase12, _Real}, {footphase21, _Real}, {footphase22, _Real}, {footphase31, _Real}, {footphase32, _Real}, {tfprevious, _Real}, {tfnext, _Real}, {\[CapitalDelta]t, _Real}},
  Which[
   tfprevious <= t1 < tfprevious + tb \[CapitalDelta]t,
   {kneephase121, kneephase122, footphase11, footphase12},
   tfprevious + tb \[CapitalDelta]t <= t1 < tfprevious + tc \[CapitalDelta]t,
   {kneephase121, kneephase122, footphase21, footphase22},
   tfprevious + tc \[CapitalDelta]t <= t1 < tfnext,
   {kneephase31, kneephase32, footphase31, footphase32},
   True,
   {0., 0., 0., 0.}
   ]
  ]
```

Admittedly, the error messages have not been very helpful in finding out what is going on...

Comment: This solved the problem. Thank you very much, didnt know a default value had to be put into Which.

Comment: @NunoTeixeira You're welcome. Glad to hear that! Indeed, `Which`does not need any explicit default in general. Here it is only about the fact that `Compile` has to generate a C-function (or rather a C++-program). And in these languages, the output type of a function has to be known at compile time.